# How to draw tick marks on a log graph?

Tags: graph, logarithm

Given a range '1 to x', with a tick mark spacing 'y' such that 'y' < 'x/2', how do I draw the tick marks on a graph in log 10?
Is there a generalized algorithm for this sort of thing?
 I should have added this is in c# for a custom control.

Comment: where are you trying to do this ? matlab ?

Comment: In .net - c# for custom control.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your x-axis is in log10 scale, you have values from `1` to `x` (which will be placed at positions from `0` to `log10(x)`, and you want to know how to pick `y` so that there will be at least three tickmarks on the graph?